# Convex function and inequality (slope)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I post here because I don't succeed to find out where I'm wrong in order to demonstrate that if $f$ is a function defined on $I$ and verifying :

$\forall x_0 \in I \quad  g_{x_0} : I\setminus\{x_0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x\rightarrow \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$

is non-decreasing function, then $f$ is convex. This is what I did :

Let $x,y \in I$ and $\lambda \in ]0;1[$, with $x \neq y$ (thus we can suppose $y > x$). We want to show that :

$$\label{main}\tag{$*$} (1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y) \geq f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)$$

So, let's $v = (1-\lambda)x+\lambda y$. Then: 
$$\lambda = \frac{v-x}{y-x}\in(0,1). $$

We have, then:

\begin{align}
(\ref{main}) &\iff \frac{y-v}{y-x}f(x) + \frac{v-x}{y-x}f(y) \geq f(v) \\
&\iff (y-v)f(x) + (v-x)f(y) \geq f(v)(y-x) \\
&\iff vf(y)+f(v)x-xf(y) \geq f(v)y-f(x)y+f(x)v \\
&\iff (v-x)f(y)+f(v)x \geq (v-y)f(x)+f(v)y \\
&\iff (v-x)(f(y)-f(v)) \geq (v-y)(f(x)-f(v)) \\
&\iff \frac{f(y)-f(v)}{v-y} \geq \frac{f(x)-f(v)}{v-x} \\
&\iff -g_v(y) \geq -g_v(x) \\
&\iff g_v(y) \leq g_v(x)
\end{align}

which is wrong cause $g$ is non decreasing. But even when I read and re-read what I've written, I don't find where I made a mistake, where is the sign problem.

Thank you !

Comment: Your error is in the second-to-last line: $x<v<y$, so $v-x>0$, but $v-y<0$, so when you divide across, the direction of the inequality flips

Comment: You can get displayed equations with double dollar signs; they're much easier to read (especially when you use fractions).